# How to get an id for the dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Table1

```
id dates

01 23/02/2011
02 24/04/2011
03 26/08/2011
...
```

I want to select the id from table1, if dates is exceeded 6 month.

Expected Output from tabl1

id dates

```
01 23/02/2011 'Dates is older than 6 month
02 24/04/2011 'Dates is older than 6 month
```

How to make a query

Need query Help

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select id, dates
from Table1
where dates < dateadd(month, -6, getdate())
```

Answer (score 1):

`select id from table1 where datediff(m, dates, getdate()) >= 6`

Comment: -1 it will do datediff for each row, it's better to do it like @MikaelEriksson suggested.

Comment: @Michał Powaga: It won't matter. I've just checked and SQL Server 2008 R2 generates exactly same execution plan, with or without index on `dates`, for both `datediff` and `dateadd` (index seek or pk scan)

Comment: you are right without index in both cases `table scan` is used, but with index in @MikaelEriksson query `index seek` can be used. So if there's a chance to gain a performance, it's better to do so.